# Golang test containers failed to create container while building from Dockerfile

Tags: go, testcontainers

I'm having my first steps with testcontainers-go library and I'm encountering such issue:

```
testcontainers_test.go:25: Error response from daemon: No such image: d79b11e4-647c-4064-9e6f-94a626c9287d:964a49e9-0b99-42f5-acba-851d95792857: failed to create container
--- FAIL: TestWithRedis (23.00s)
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
        panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0xe0 pc=0x8d6731]
```

My source code is almost identical to the one from docs

```golang
package xx

import (
    "context"
    "testing"

    "github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go"
)

var token = "xxx"
var customVersion = "v1.11"
var http_proxy = "xxx"
var https_proxy = "xxx"
var no_proxy = "xxx"

func TestWithRedis(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    req := testcontainers.ContainerRequest{FromDockerfile: testcontainers.FromDockerfile{
        Context:    "/home/usr/project", // this is where I have my Dockerfile
        Dockerfile: "Dockerfile",
        BuildArgs: map[string]*string{
            "TOKEN":               &token,
            "CUSTOM_VERSION": &customVersion,
            "http_proxy":          &http_proxy,
            "https_proxy":         &https_proxy,
            "no_proxy":            &no_proxy,
        },
    },
    }
    redisC, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(ctx, testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
        ContainerRequest: req,
        Started:          true,
        ProviderType:     0,
        Logger:           nil,
        Reuse:            false,
    })
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err) // this is line 25 where the error from above refers to
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := redisC.Terminate(ctx); err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("failed to terminate container: %s", err.Error())
        }
    }()
}
```

When I'm building from command line everything works fine:

`docker build --pull --build-arg TOKEN="xxx" --build-arg CUSTOM_VERSION="v1.11" --build-arg http_proxy --build-arg https_proxy --build-arg no_proxy .`

Any idea what is going on? The Dockerfile works fine by itself so that's not the case and the error information doesn't help me at all.

Comment: The issue may happen due to the  `FROM` image you have in the docker file is invalid or unable to pull the image or unable to build the image or something else. But the issue should be related to the Image, that is why it is returning `No such image` error. Please update your question with the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC I've added more details about build args and how I run it from shell and it works, I'd rather not pass the Dockerfile since it contains too much company details. Also since it works from bash I don't see why would the content of Dockerfile itself should matter

Comment: can you list the docker images and check for this one: `d79b11e4-647c-4064-9e6f-94a626c9287d:964a49e9-0b99-42f5-acba-851d95792857`

Comment: @Pygirl such image doesn't exist also regading to your previous commend if I'm pulling this image instead of building by myself it works fine.

Comment: @Pygirl At doesn't help at all since the build hash will change with every execution so instead of `d79(...)` there will be another value.

Answer (score 0):

After using `PrintBuildLog: true`, it shows that the reason is the usage of buildkit, apparently looks like at this moment testcontainters do not have any solution for it.